# Directory index forbidden by Options directive error only for ruby 1.8.7 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, phusion

This is driving me nuts.

I have 2 different rails app running on the same redhat server. The web server is apache and app server is passenger 5.0

> App1 - rails 3.0.2 and ruby 1.9.3
>
> App2- rails 2.0.3 & ruby 1.8.7

App1 works fine and this is the configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName server-xyz
    RailsEnv test
    DocumentRoot /webapps/test/app1/current/public
    <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I run app2 it takes me to the default apache page and gives me the following error:

> Directory index forbidden by Options directive:
>   /webapps/test/app2/current/public/

This is the virtual host for app2:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName server-xyz
    RailsEnv test
    DocumentRoot /webapps/test/app2/current/public
    <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the common passgenger configuration:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /opt/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.8/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /opt/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.8
PassengerDefaultRuby /opt/ree-1.8.7/bin/ruby_with_env

PassengerLogLevel 1
PassengerMaxPoolSize 10
```

Anyone has any ideas why it works for ruby.1.9.3 app and not for ruby 1.8.7?

I tried following similar threads but couldnt get it to work.

EDIT: I gave 'apache' write permissions to that path. Didn't seem to help.

EDIT 2: I found the following .htaccess configuration under public:

```
/webapps/test/app2/releases/20150622171404/public/.htaccess
# General Apache options
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI


RewriteEngine On

# If your Rails application is accessed via an Alias directive,
# then you MUST also set the RewriteBase in this htaccess file.
#
# Example:
#   Alias /myrailsapp /path/to/myrailsapp/public
#   RewriteBase /myrailsapp

RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.cgi [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on passenger 5 and running ruby 1.8.7 & rails 2 app, you need to add a config.ru to the root of your application:

```
# config.ru
# Require your environment file to bootstrap Rails
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'

# Serve static assets from RAILS_ROOT/public directory
# use Rails::Rack::Static
# Dispatch the request
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second application configuration, update it with:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName server-xyz
    RailsEnv test
    DocumentRoot /webapps/test/app2/current/public
    <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and check the filesystem that you don't have a .htaccess file with custom configuration for the Indexes option either on the app directory or on a upper directory

Comment: thanks rorra. I posted the .htaccess file that I found. Do i need to update it? I followed your suggestion and restarted apache but with no success.

Comment: replace `Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI` with `Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Indexes`

Comment: I tried that. Also tried removing the .htaccess completely and retry. I still get the same error:Directory index forbidden by Options directive:

Comment: And just to be double sure, when doing these updates, you restarted/reload apache, right? Because the indexes option is due to apache configuration, not related to ruby

Comment: yes, i restarted them each time and double checked.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.X. I found the easiest option was to downgrade from passenger 5 to passenger 4.0.59.